# Add emoji=true to .flowconfig

Tags: javascript, configuration, flowtype

I was trying out the flow configuration options and I noticed that The [options] heading can contain a key 'emoji'.

> emoji (boolean): set this to true and Flow will use emoji in server status messages. The default value is false.

However, when I add it to my .flowconfig file like this

```
[options]
emoji=true
```

I get an error when running flow which states the following:

> .flowconfig:17 Unsupported option specified! (emoji)

Should I import the emoji option from somewhere or prefix it with a module name?

[Flow options](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs have been updated but [that pull request](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/3000) was only merged a week ago. It hasn't been released yet, but I believe it should go out with Flow v0.38.0. I don't know exactly when that will be released, but I would expect it in the next few weeks.

I just built Flow from source and tested it out and it does indeed work as expected :)

Comment: Yes, as stated by Nat, the pull request is merged but there is no release since then. Thanks!

Comment: Flow v0.38.0 is now out, so you should be able to update and use the emoji option.

Comment: I've just installed 0.38.0 and I get the same error. Seems it's not implemented yet.

Comment: I'm sure it's implemented and released, I've used it myself. Maybe you misspelled the option name, or you have multiple versions of Flow installed somehow and an older one is getting invoked.